# Difference Between WinRM - and [T] Related Tasks in TFS 2015 vNext On Promise Deployment

Tags: deployment, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

What is different between the above two sets of deployment methods?  I can find the **WinRM** related information in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/sql-server-database-deployment and
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/other-servers/net-to-vm, but not any info about **[T]** related tasks.

**[T]** related tasks seem to be simpler since we can avoid installing WinRM and openning additional ports.  Are these new tasks without documentation yet?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tasks come from an extension in https://github.com/TechnossusLLC/On-Premises-Release-Toolkit/blob/master/deploydatabase.md